# XSLT: inject an element into another element

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to inject xml elements in another xml elements using an id element to join.

For example:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <id>1</id>
        <!-- other elements ... -->
    </a>
    <a>
        <id>2</id>
        <!-- other elements ... -->
    </a>
    <b>
        <id>10</id>
        <ref>1</ref>
        <!-- other elements ... -->
    </b>
    <b>
        <id>13</id>
        <ref>2</ref>
        <!-- other elements ... -->
    </b>
    <b>
        <id>13</id>
        <ref>1</ref>
        <!-- other elements ... -->
    </b>
</root>
```

And I need to transform to:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <id>1</id>
        <!-- other elements ... -->
        <b>
            <id>10</id>
            <ref>1</ref>
            <!-- other elements ... -->
        </b>
        <b>
            <id>13</id>
            <ref>1</ref>
            <!-- other elements ... -->
        </b>

    </a>
    <a>
        <id>2</id>
        <!-- other elements ... -->
        <b>
            <id>13</id>
            <ref>2</ref>
            <!-- other elements ... -->
        </b>
    </a>
</root>
```

In this case I join the b element into an element when **a/id** is equal to **b/ref**.

Is possible make this kind de transformation using XSLT? How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First start off with the identity template, to copy nodes to the output document as-is

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

To enable the efficient looking up of **b** elements by their **ref**, consider creating a key:

```
<xsl:key name="b" match="b" use="ref" />
```

Then, you can have a template to match **a** elements, where you can both output the **a** element as normal, and copy the associated **b** elements, using the key

```
<xsl:template match="a">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('b', id)" />
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Finally, you would need a template to stop the **b** elements being output normally by the identity template:

```
<xsl:template match="b" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="b" match="b" use="ref" />
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="a">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
         <xsl:copy-of select="key('b', id)" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="b" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```